# Thicker cerebrospinal fluid: Results?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, evolution, creature-design

[Cerebrospinal fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebrospinal_fluid) is a thin layer of liquid that helps use avoid being knocked out (among other uses). Creatures with a thicker layer have more trouble being knocked out. I want my humanoids to naturally evolve a thicker layer of this fluid. How can I achieve this, and will there be other effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I achieve this[?]

**Make them cavemen.**

Cerebrospinal fluid (CSF) keeps the brain in neutral buoyancy, effectively lessening its weight against itself. This means that the brain can be heavier than it would be otherwise, meaning that it can be denser. Increasing the amount of CSF would mean that the brain could be even denser and still be neutrally buoyant. You might then see more folds in the brain, with increased surface area. Although the size of the brain will decrease, an increase in density could lead to more brain cells.

More brain cells don't necessarily correspond to greater intelligence. [*Homo neanderthalensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal) is a case in point here, with heavier brains but not necessarily greater intelligence than modern-day humans. However, a more massive brain could certainly help.

While more CSF means a smaller brain size, [as bowlturner said](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/29128/627), it might still lead to an increase in brain mass.

How could you get a thicker layer of CSF? I'm always inclined to say that randomness in evolution will lead to a variety of different results; the mutation in question simply has to significantly affect the organism enough to make it dominant in a species (or lead to a new species). This means that environmental factors may come into play, and I'm inclined to say that the possibility for a slightly higher average intelligence won't be as important.

Therefore, I would suggest that the reason for a thicker layer of CSF could be motivated by its ability to protect the brain. Perhaps the humanoids live in an area where they get banged up quite a bit. They might live in caves that have an unfortunate tendency to cave in, or in forests that tend to have a lot of falling trees. The point is, I'm pretty sure that they'll need to have an environment where they get hit on the head a lot.

Now, a thicker layer of CSF won't necessarily mean a *denser* layer of CSF, and given that (as [Samuel pointed out](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29127/thicker-cerebrospinal-fluid-results#comment76655_29134)) the density of the fluid is what determines buoyancy, it might not lead to a substantial effect. So I enter Crazy Scenario #1, which is that the humanoids manage to - on a small scale - change the size/shape of their skulls for some purpose. Perhaps they need to squeeze into small places (tiny cave tunnels) to hide, hibernate, or live, which means they have to somehow change the shape of their bodies. This would mean that an alternate skull structure/material is needed. [Cartilage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartilage) could be used here. It is still hard, but not as hard as bone, meaning that some deformation is allowed (although not a lot - think of what it's like to have a broken nose!).

Unlikely? Perhaps. But cave-dwelling humanoids living in small tunnels (if you'll run with my one of my suggested premises) are bound to be different.

[Ville Niemi suggested higher gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29127/thicker-cerebrospinal-fluid-results#comment76670_29134) an another factor that might be important. Impacts would be even more forceful, leading to a need for substantially stronger cushioning.

Comment: Good point, but unless you increase the density, not just the volume there won't be a gain.

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest explanation be to just dial up the gravity a bit? Higher gravity means higher impact when you fall down. Or even when you jump, run, or walk. This would naturally adjust the optimal CSF thickness to be higher than at 1G to compensate for the higher typical impacts. Alternately you can copy from animals that have horns. If you have horns for head butting for some reason, higher impact resistance would be likely.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Interesting idea. You do have the problem bowlturner mentioned, though, with the higher gravity: More weight on the neck.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Anyway, I edited a mention of your idea into the answer, because it's a good point.

Comment: Why would having a stronger neck be a problem? Anything that requires more shock absorption for the brain will almost certainly require stronger neck anyway since the neck muscles are a part of the protection mechanism and upper spine is part of what is protected.

Answer (score 4):

The effect is head-size vs brain-size.  The thicker the fluid, the larger the skull must be or the smaller the brain must be.  Something has to give.

If you keep heads the same then if more volume is taken up by the fluid, then there will be less space for brain matter. (one reason we likely have less is we gave it up for brain cell space, trading the protection for more smarts.

So if the brain stays the same, then the skull must get bigger.  This would give bigger heads and also more weight sitting on top of the neck, making whiplash a possible fatal accident unless you increase the the neck muscles and bones to handle the larger mass.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this. Good idea though neck neck large headed aliens would have a pretty unique look

Comment: what he said.  its all about shock absorption and that requires distance.

Comment: Bigger heads also means more traumatic births, assuming you have the birth canal routed through the pelvis as it is in humans (which is certainly not your only option here).

Comment: Very true.   I should have had that in my answer

Answer (score 2):

**Make it more viscous rather than a thicker layer of it.**

This way the creature doesn't need to have a larger head or a smaller brain but will attain increased protection from shock. If the humanoids can get some connective tissue growing between the brain and skull, like adipose, they'll be as well off [as a woodpecker](http://mentalfloss.com/article/30731/why-dont-woodpeckers-get-brain-damage) and could bang their heads against trees all day long.

Of course, they'll be literal fat heads. But don't call them that, they can easily headbutt you in a fight and win.

Note that viscosity is correlated with density. To maintain the density ratio between the more viscous fluid and the brain, the density of the brain should also be increased. As [HDE226868 suggested](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/29134/3202).